# How to delete and update based on a path in System.Text.Json (.NET 6)?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a JSON text:

```json
{
   "a":[
      {
         "a1":"string",
         "a2":"string",
         "a3":"string"
      }
   ],
   "b":"2021-12-29T14:20:21.948Z",
   "c":{
      "c1":[
         {
            "c11":"string",
            "c12":"string",
            "c13":"string",
            "c14":true,
            "c15":true,
            "c16":"2021-12-29T14:20:21.948Z",
            "c17":"string"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

`JsonNode` class always has a unique `path` I want to use them to find a specific value (update/delete them).

[image]

So, I want to use `System.Text.Json` and `.NET 6` to have the following methods:

```cs
public static JsonNode UpdateValue(string json /*JsonNode json*/, string path, object value)
{
    // ?
}

public static JsonNode RemovePath(string json /*JsonNode json*/, string path)
{
    // ?
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking that if you know the path of a given node then can you update or delete it?

Comment: Exactly, I know the path now in my code, I want to be able to delete and update based on it.

Comment: Since by definition *JsonNode is a modifiable, dictionary-backed API to complement the readonly JsonDocument* I would say yes.

Comment: My question is how?! I need those methods. I tried but I cannot find manipulation API there. Can you share the snippet code?

Comment: Yepp, sure. I will put together a sample.

Comment: By the way your sample json contains `c17` field twice.

Comment: I was wrong you can't :( I have left a post where I detailed the reasoning. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Unfortunately you can't

#### Modification

`JsonDocument` is readonly by design. Before `JsonNode` has been introduced you had to

1. deserialize it as `Dictionary<string, object>`
2. perform the modification
3. serialize it back to json

Since [JsonNode](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/docs/writable_json_dom_spec.md#modifying-existing-instance) has been introduced in .NET 6 you can do the following

```
var node = JsonNode.Parse(json);
var rootObject = node as JsonObject;
var aArray = rootObject["a"] as JsonArray;
var firstA = aArray[0];
firstA["a3"] = "modified";
```

or in short

```
var node = JsonNode.Parse(json);
node["a"][0]["a3"] = "modified";
```

#### Locate element by Path

Even though the [need has been expressed in 2019](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31068) it hasn't been address yet. But as `layomia` said

> This feature is proposed for .NET 6, but not committed. To be clear, we acknowledge that this is an important feature for many users, however, work on features with higher priority may prevent this from coming in .NET 6.

Unfortunately this feature did not make it to the .NET 6.

There are 3rd party libraries which offers this capability for `JsonDocument`. One of the most mature one is called [JsonDocumentPath](https://github.com/azambrano/JsonDocumentPath). With its `SelectElement` method you can really easily retrieve the given field as `JsonElement`

```
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
JsonElement? a3 = doc.RootElement.SelectElement("$.a[0].a3");
```

#### Interoperability

Even though [there is a way to convert](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52611) `JsonElement` to `JsonNode` and in the other way around:

```
var a3Node = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(a3.Value);
a3Node = "a";
```

it does not really help since the `a3Node` represents only the `a3` field and according to my understanding you can't just merge two `JsonNode`s.

Answer (score -3):

update json using Newtonsoft.Json

```
 string json = File.ReadAllText("json");
    dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    jsonObj["a"][0]["test1"] = "new values";
    string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: The question is specifically stating that he is using System.Text.Json not Newtonsoft.

Comment: The question asks how to modify data using a JSON path, something supported by JSON.NET but not System.Text.Json. This answer doesn't use JSON path